# How to remove all elements except for one, maintaing the same CSS path to it?

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I need to extract a single element (and all its contents) from a page, but still maintaining the same CSS tree that points to it.

To explain, let's say I have the following DOM:

```
<div>1
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3
        <div>4
            <div>5</div>
        </div>6
        <div>7
            <div>8
                <div>9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>10
            <div>
                <div>content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am only interested in the element containing `content`, i.e. I need to transform the DOM in:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(the path to `content` should still be the same)

I am trying something like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9Tc4/):

```
$("#want").siblings().html("");
$("#want").parents().siblings().html("");
```

which does not seem to be enough.

Suggestions?

EDIT: generalised the example, there can be any element instead of divs.

Comment: #want points directly to an ID, there is no "css tree" involved in this.

Comment: Do you mean that the HTML *structure* has to remain the same, but that you need to remove all content except for the content within *want*? If so, can you just use an **if not** statement to empty everything except the `#want` div?

Comment: I don't get this at all, but `$('div').not('#want').empty();`

Comment: disregard the id, I have a CSS path that points to a DOM element. I want to maintain the path to that element while removing all the rest.

Comment: @adeneo: That will remove all divs. It will delete the parent div because the parent div matches the selector: it is a div, and not() #want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sintax

```
$(function(){
   $("div:not(#want)").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
   }).remove();     
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to know, but sadly does not seem to solve my problem: I need everything inside #want.. http://jsfiddle.net/S9Tc4/9/

Comment: Thats because the values are nested in the div you want, your example didnt show that :P Add the keep-class to #want>* to keep everything. The nextnodes remain though, you have to think of something for that (though you shoudl prefer to place all text in belonging elements)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var classForKeepings = 'keepThisItem';
var $elem = $('#want'); // give start element
$elem.addClass(classForKeepings); // give a class to make it stay

while( $elem.parent().length!==0 ){ // while the element has a parent
    $elem = $elem.parent(); // shift $elem to the parent
    $elem.addClass(classForKeepings ); // and add a class to make it stay
}

$('#startElement *:not(.'+classForKeepings+')').remove(); // remove all elements not tagged with the class
$('.'+classForKeepings ).removeClass(classForKeepings); // Cleanup afterwards
```

I used remove, since you dont need them. If you do need those, you can change it to `.html('')`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working.. too bad I need it to work with [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) but it seems there is no `contents()`.. guess I will have to use jsdom instead.. if I cannot find another solution..

```
$("#want").siblings().html("");
$("#want").parents().siblings().html("");
var want = $("#want").clone();
$("*").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
 }).remove();
$("#want").replaceWith(want);
```